# How to notify android app that web-service url is changed

Tags: android, web-services

I have 5,6 android app which uses same URL(hard coded in apps) to invoke HTTP requests, the problem is that if the  URL is changed due some reasons i have to re upload all apps with new URL which is a problem for me and i am looking for a solution for this.

I can build a web service to check for valid URL at initialization or connect to a remote database to get new URL but problem is that they need static IP and in my case i don't have it.

Is there is any method to notify and send small amount of data without having static IP.

Comment: just use any free file server (even your google docs with public) put the json file with servers url there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different way to include URL in your app, like a configuration file or some like this, and when you need to update the url you can do this with a simple GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) message with a payload, but you need to implement GCM requests handling in your app.

GCM permitt to send message without the need of a static IP

Comment: upon registration i have to send registration id to server and for this i need a static ip.

Comment: you can do the same with dynamic dns, you need only a url, for instace you can use a very simple backend hosted in a free hosting service like OpenShift bronze, or something similar, in this way you have a "static" server where you send registration id, and you can use this server for pushing gcm requestes

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i found for this issue is to use MongoDB which free for <500mb i can easily update MongoDb and my app can retrive String from it.